# Firebase Firestore Security Rules: Allow subset of fields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a database where my user document can have the following fields:

```
['name', 'email', 'dob', 'gender', 'country', 'profile', `notificationToken`]
```

I want the document to be created when the request document has a **subset of these fields**
Neither `hasAll()` works here (as to-be-created document might not have all fields) nor `hasAny()` works (as to-be-created document must not contain an invalid field like `'photo'`).

Plus, I want that if a field, for example, `'name'` is present, it should be a string. Now if I use:

```
allow create, update: if request.resource.data.name is string
```

And if the `name` field is not present in my to-be-created document, (which would be the case if I set the notificationToken field later and use `setOptions.merge()`), it returns false or error as I am not setting the field. But I want it to only force that `string` datatype if the field is present. I also want to do the same where I can set the profile object individually and use merge, but also forcing the datatype.

Is there a way to accomplish this in security rules?

Answer (score 1):

To check for a subset of fields you can use `hasAll` in the opposite direction to achieve the desired effect, e.g.:

```
allow create, update: if ['name', 'email', 'dob', 'gender', 'country', 'profile', 'notificationToken'].hasAll(request.resource.data.keys());
```